# ASP.NET MVC validation for knockout observable array

Tags: asp.net-mvc, knockout.js, asp.net-mvc-5, knockout-3.0

I'm working on a form that has one grid filled using a collection (observable array), to fill that arrays I use a modal window and add the new element to the array, and the grid uses the foreach binding to draw the items, that is working ok.

The thing is I need to validate (client and server) the grid must have items to submit the form, my mvc model has a property to receive that collection, something like

```
[Required(ErrorMessage = "Events are required")]
public List<Event> Events { get; set; }
```

To submit the form I'm using a button just like this

```
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-success btn-xs" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="Save Data" data-bind="click: saveData">
<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-cloud-upload"></span> Save </button>
```

It uses a javascript function in the knockout viewModel, there I call the jqueryvalidations

```
self.saveData = function() {
    if ($("#myForm").valid()) {
        $.ajax({
            url: mvcActionUrl,
            type: "POST",
            data: formData,
            dataType: "json"
        })
    }
};
```

With calling valid() on the form all the setted validations (data annotations) works, but regarging the grid I have no idea how to check if the Observable Array has items and then show the message setted on the [Required] attribute using the @ValidationMessageFor helper.

I'm very new to knockout I will appreciate your help

Comment: You should realize that though you can get [jQuery validation + knockoutjs](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5734851/419956) to work, there also is an alternative in the form of [knockout-validation](https://github.com/Knockout-Contrib/Knockout-Validation). Either way, the question as posted is rather broad, and doesn't contain the code needed to reproduce the situation you seem to have...

Comment: `if (self.YourObservableArray().length < 1 ) self.ShowYourMessage(true)`