# Validate automatically on button press

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation, knockout.js

Hi I am using JQuery Form validator to validate a form, and using knockout js to call a function using a button, What I want is that when the button is clicked the the knockout js function should be called, and also at the same time check if all the fields are validated if not, it should just do nothing till all the fields are validated.
Link for the jquery validator form http://www.formvalidator.net/#advanced_programmatically

Here is a field and the button that calls the function.

```
<input type="text" name="birthday" data-validation="date" data-validation-format="yyyy-mm-dd" placeholder="yyyy-mm-dd" data-validation-help="You must be more than 20 years old" class="form-control" value="<?php if (isset($user['Birthday'])) {echo $user['Birthday'];} ?>">
<div data-bind="ifnot: (loggedIn() == 'true')"> 
            <button data-bind="click : openUpTwoStepAuth " type="submit" id="openUpTwoStepAuth" class="btn registerbtn">
                <?php echo lang("register_continue_btn"); ?>
            </button>
        </div>
```

And here is the knockout js function that tries to call the validation as soon as the button is clicked, but in my case it does not check the validation and goes on with the ajax call.

```
self.openUpTwoStepAuth = function(){
            $('#openUpTwoStepAuth').validate(function(valid, elem) {
                if(!valid){
                    return;
                }
             });
            self.emailtokenconfirmation(false);
            self.tokenError(null);
            self.showTwoStepAuth();
            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: BASEURL + 'index.php/myprofile/sendEmailForTwoStepAuth/',
                contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
                data: ko.toJSON({customerEmail : self.customerEmail()})
            })
            .done(function(data) {
                if(data.success){
                    self.emailtokenconfirmation(true);
                }else{
                    self.tokenError(data.result);
                }
            })
            .fail(function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                alert("Error code thrown: " + errorThrown);
            })
            .always(function(data){

            });   
        }
```

It works fine if its just a normal button calling the submit function with this piece of code

```
<script>
  $.validate({
    modules : 'toggleDisabled',
    disabledFormFilter : 'form.toggle-disabled',
    showErrorDialogs : false
  });
</script>
```

but for me I want to call a js function and at the same time check the validation of the field.

Comment: Try placing your ajax where your validation gets true. `if (!valid){return}else{//your ajax}` .Also you may want to use `knockout. extend` to do validation. since you are using knockout

Comment: @Matt.kaaj the thing is that if i check console.log(valid) , there is no return value

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be already answered here

[Knockout + Jquery Validate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5734851/knockout-jquery-validate)

Use submitHandler in validate to call your view model function on successful validation.